# What is the equivalent of force_download methode in codeIgniter 4

Tags: php, file, codeigniter, file-get-contents, force-download

I'm trying to allowed download file from writable path in codeIgniter 4
this code don't match

```php
helper('download');
            // read file contents
            //$data = file_get_contents(WRITEPATH.'uploads/'.$filename);
    
             $data = file_get_contents(base_url().'/uploads/'.$filename, TRUE);
            force_download($filename, $data);
```

I get  this error :
Call to undefined function

```php
App\Controllers\force_download()
```

Thanks to help me

Answer (score 3):

If you have a direct path for your file you can use `download()` method from `$response`

```
return $response->download('/path/to/photo.jpg', null);
```

optionally you can use `setFileName()` to set name for a file when sent to browser

```
return $response->download('/path/to/photo.jpg', null)->setFileName('some.jpg');
```

[Reference: Force File Download](https://codeigniter4.github.io/userguide/outgoing/response.html#force-file-download)

Answer (score 3):

In CI 3 we use helper to load our download functionality and the method is force_download.
In CI 4 we use $response to download our file below is the code which downloads the file:

```
public function download($id){
        $superadminModel = model('App\Models\SuperAdminModel');
        $fileinfo = $superadminModel->download($id);// get name of file using ID
        $file = ROOTPATH.'/uploads/documents/'.$File['doc'];//file location+filename
        return $this->response->download($file, null);//download file
    }
```

ROOTPATH.'/uploads/documents/' this location for your file could be different so instead of this location add the location of your file

Comment: Can you also suggest how to download via REST API?

Comment: Sorry, I have not learned RUST, I was learning CI4 and 3 at that time